# WinForms - detect if any dialog windows are open

Tags: .net, winforms, dialog, window

I have a timer in the main application form.

The timer displays a nag screen every N seconds.

But I'd like to avoid showing the nag screen if any modal dialog windows are open. Otherwise overlapping will occur.

I can use `Application.OpenForms`, but this doesn't count dialogs such as `OpenFileDialog`.

How to detect if any child dialogs are currently shown?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this 100% reliably.  Just incrementing a public static variable before the ShowDialog() calls and decrementing it afterward is the best approach.

Comment: @HansPassant: You mention lack of a simple way to achieve this reliably. Could you hint at how one would go about approaching this short of tracking static variables all over a complicated form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using these Win32 apis:

> [GetForegroundWindow();](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getforegroundwindow)
>   [GetAncestor(foregroundWindow, GA_ROOTOWNER);](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAncestor.html)
>   [GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, out activeProcessId)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html)